# How can I keep hidden columns hidden once workbook is converted to HTML?

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a script that goes through an excel workbook, hides certain rows and columns, and then publishes the workbook to HTML. For some reason, the hidden rows stay hidden once converted, but the hidden columns do not. They are hidden in the excel version of the workbook, but once converted to HTML they actually expand and ruin the format of everything else.

I have tried both using the SaveAs command, saving as xlHtml, as well as the publish command. Both of these successfully converted the document to HTML and kept the rows hidden, however neither kept the columns hidden.

```
'Sets which sheets to search through and update
sheetList = Array("CH01", "CH02", "CH03", "CH04", "CH05", "CH06", "CH07", 
"CH08", "CH09")

For sheetNum = LBound(sheetList) To UBound(sheetList)
    'sets sh to each sheet in sheetList
    Set sh = Sheets(sheetList(sheetNum))

    'Hides first four rows of each sheet in sheetList
    sh.Columns("A:D").Hidden = True
Next

'Save Method one
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\test.html", _
FileFormat:=xlHtml  

'Save Method Two
With ActiveWorkbook
    With .PublishObjects(1)
    .Filename = "publishtest.htm"
    .Publish
    End With
End With
```

The conversion process always takes awhile, around two to four minutes, and the output file has all of the expected rows hidden, which I hide with the same method in another piece of code.

Once I run the piece of code above, I always check the excel version of the workbook and it has the correct rows AND columns hidden, however the converted HTML version only has the correct rows hidden. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might try creating a copy of the worksheet, then deleting those columns (maybe the rows too if you want), then save that (temporary) worksheet as HTML.

Comment: Exactly.  How could you expect hidden columns to be hidden when the content is converted to HTML???

Comment: @asher The thing is it works with the rows. I hide certain rows using the same code and they do not show up in HTML.

Comment: Wow.  Interesting.  I assumed it did NOT work like that.  I guess that's what I get for making this assumption.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, using @PeterT 's suggestion as well as moving the file to a local folder. I forgot I was using a remote drive, and the downloading process must have taken too long for vba to edit the columns before it converted to html. Interestingly, hiding the columns still did not work, I had to delete them. Here is my code

```
'Sets which sheets to search through and update
sheetList = Array("CH01", "CH02", "CH03", "CH04", "CH05", "CH06", "CH07", "CH08", "CH09")

'Saves and opens new workbook to process and convert to html. 
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs _
Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & test & ".xlsm"
Workbooks.Open (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & test & ".xlsm")

For sheetNum = LBound(sheetList) To UBound(sheetList)
    'sets sh to each sheet in sheetList
    Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetList(sheetNum))

    'Deletes first four rows of each sheet in sheetList (only way to hide columns once converted to html)
    sh.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
    sh.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
    sh.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
    sh.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
Next
```